# Using toFixed in the right place

Tags: javascript

I have a form which outputs a calculation from an input field and a drop down.

The script is fine apart from the grand total.  When you type in a figure and select a value from the drop down, the grand total is rounded to 2 decimal places in the html.

Can anyone see why this is happening?

The form is below:

```
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" maxlength="6" autocomplete="off"/><span class="paymentalert" style="color:red;"></span>
<br /><br />
<label for="delivery">Delivery:</label>
<select id="delivery" name="delivery">
    <option value="1.50">Fast</option>
    <option value="2.50">Medium</option>
    <option value="3.50">Slow</option>
</select>
```

The javascript is below:

```
function updateCost()
{
    var amount = parseFloat($('#amount').val()).toFixed(2);
    var delivery = parseFloat($('#delivery').val()).toFixed(2);   

    var total = parseFloat(amount) + parseFloat(delivery);
    $("#total").html(total);
    $("#amountdiv").html(amount);
    $("#deliverydiv").html(delivery);

    var fixedrate =  parseFloat(total / 100 * 8.2).toFixed(2);

    var grandtotal = parseFloat(fixedrate) + parseFloat(total);
    $("#grandtotal").html(grandtotal);
    $("#total").html(total);
    $("#fixedrate").html(fixedrate);    

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#amount').change(function(){ updateCost(); });
    $('#delivery').change(function(){ updateCost(); });
    $('#grandtotal').change(function(){ updateCost(); });
});
```

Comment: Should the grand total *not* be rounded to two decimal places?

Comment: It's not calculating to two decimal places.  When I input 40.76 for example and then select 1.50 or 3.50, it rounds to 2 decimal places fine.  When I select 2.50, the decimal places over run.  Weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toFixed(2)` should only be used in the part of the code that outputs it. In this case, you should have constructs like `$("#someID").html(total.toFixed(2))`, and remove the extra `parseFloat()`s. Something like this:

```
function updateCost() {
    var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value),
        delivery = parseFloat(document.getElementById("delivery").value),
        total = amount + delivery,
        fixedrate =  total / 100 * 8.2,
        grandtotal = fixedrate + total;

    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("amountdiv").innerHTML = amount.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("deliverydiv").innerHTML = delivery.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("grandtotal").innerHTML = grandtotal.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("fixedrate").innerHTML = fixedrate.toFixed(2);
}

$(function(){
    document.getElementById("amount").onchange =
        document.getElementById("delivery").onchange = updateCost;
});
```

Comment: Wow..Thank you.  You really did simplify what I did.  Excellent. Plus I've learnt.